# Merge dicts in one and find mean

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new in programming.
I have lists of dicts.

```
 [{'Program Analysis': 0},
 {'Algorithms': 0},
 {'Number systems': 0},
 {'Game theory': 1},
 {'Algorithms': 1},
 {'Number systems': 0},
 {'Program Analysis': 0}]
```

I want to merge all dicts in one and then find mean.

```
{'Program Analysis': [0, 0]},
 'Algorithms': [0, 1],
 'Number systems': [0, 0],
 'Game theory': 1 }




{'Program Analysis': 0},
 'Algorithms': 0.5,
 'Number systems': 0,
 'Game theory': 1 }
```

Comment: Will all the dictionaries have the same entries?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def avg(num_list):
    total = 0
    for num in num_list:
        total += num
    return total * 1.0 / len(num_list)

my_list =  [{'Program Analysis': 0}, {'Algorithms': 0}, {'Number systems': 0}, {'Game theory': 1}, {'Algorithms': 1}, {'Number systems': 0}, {'Program Analysis': 0}]
result = dict()

for d in my_list:
    for name, num in d.items():
        if name in result:
            result[name].append(num)
        else:
            result[name] = [num]

for name, num_list in result.items():
    result[name] = avg(num_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default dictionary to group the data and use mean function from statistics to calculate it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

data = [
    {'Program Analysis': 0},
    {'Algorithms': 0},
    {'Number systems': 0},
    {'Game theory': 1},
    {'Algorithms': 1},
    {'Number systems': 0},
    {'Program Analysis': 0}
]

grouped_data = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        grouped_data[k].append(v)

grouped_data = dict(grouped_data)
print(grouped_data)
>>> {'Program Analysis': [0, 0], 'Algorithms': [0, 1], 'Number systems': [0, 0], 'Game theory': [1]}


mean_data = {
    k: mean(v) for k, v in grouped_data.items()
}
print(mean_data)
>>> {'Program Analysis': 0, 'Algorithms': 0.5, 'Number systems': 0, 'Game theory': 1}
```